# Are openvpn and pptp mutually interchangeable?

Tags: vpn, virtualization, openvpn, pptp

I mean, can I use `openvpn` client to connect to `pptp` server, or vice versa: `pptp` client to connect to `openvpn` server?

I'm building a virtualized mock-up of an ISP infrastructure, which uses the VPN connection to authenticate users. The specific software that runs the ISP's VPN server is unknown. But the common way to connect to it is known (usually, `pptp-linux` on Linux, and `Connect to virtual private network` on Win).

I installed `pptpd` server to act as VPN server, but it's setup and terminology looks very archaic. Can I use `openvpn` server as a substitution to `pptpd`, so it can accept connections made by client-side `pptp-linux`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No openvpn and pptp use completely different protocols [(SSL for opevpn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openvpn), and well [pptp for pptp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pptp)).  They are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe OpenVPN uses its own propriatory protocol, so no, they are not interchangable.